# Creating a .txt error output file in protractor made manually not console errors

Tags: javascript, protractor

Hello guys I'm kinda new to js and protractor and I just found out it can't create and modify files, so the question I want to ask is:
Is it possible  to manually write test cases logic fails to a text file for example:
 I know the code is not correct but you will get the idea i know about jasmine-reporters and with xml file output but it just prints console errors i want one that is custom liek the one below

```
describe('File output test', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; 
    browser.get('https://www.google.com');    

  });

  it('Tests output file',function(){      
      var searchText = $('#lst-ib');
      searchText.sendKeys('Testt')
      searchText.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
      browser.sleep(3000);
      if(browser.getTitle() != 'Test')
      {
          var txtFile = "C:\Users\y\Desktop\test.txt";
          var file = new File(txtFile);
          var url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
          file.open("w");         

          file.writeln("Error at " + url);
          file.close();
      }



  });
});
```

conf file pretty basic:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

So I simply want to check for the given title at the moment and if it is different from the expected one i want to save the url in an output file so when the test ends i can check afterwards where exactly did something i didnt want happened. I hope I am not talking nonsense

Comment: And i know browser.getCurrentUrl(); returns a promise not the current url just couldnt think of something else,i also know it can be achieved with expect() i just want to know if this way is possible

Answer (score 0):

Protractor runs in Node.js environment. So everything, that Node.js has, is available to you. Such as ["fs" module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). So you can manually save file every time, or (as a better option), write [custom Jasmine reporter](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html). Your reporter would expose some variable or function in global namespace to register custom errors and write them into a file after test execution.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i found the answer to my question here is my sample code i used to test it

```
var fs = require('fs-extra')
var file = 'C:/Users/y/Desktop/test/New folder/output.txt'
var counter = 1;
describe('File output test', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; 
    browser.get('https://www.facebook.com');


  });

  it('Tests output file',function(){    
        email = 'dame@hotmail.com';
        pass = 'test123'
      var enterMail = $('#email');

      enterMail.sendKeys(email);
      var enterPass = $('#pass');

      enterPass.sendKeys(pass);

      enterPass.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);

      browser.sleep(3000);

        if(browser.getTitle() != 'Facebook'){




        fs.appendFile(file,counter +'. ' + 'Error at login using: ('+email +') as email and ('+pass+') as password.' + "\n" , function (err) {

        console.log(err) // => null 




        })
        counter+=1;
        }








  });
});
```

I found a module fs-extra which allowed to create and edit some files or documents and i managed to create and write my manual output in a file here is the link to fs-extra https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#mkdirsdir-callback in case someone needs it cheers